# Iterating through Pandas Groupby and Merging DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like it should be straightforward but is stumping me. Really love being able to iterate through the groups of a groupby operation and I am getting the result I want from the groupby but I am unable to merge the final result into one dataframe. So essentially I have the below code which can capture the dataframes in a list but I don't know how to loop through a list of dataframes to make one dataframe:

```
dfs = []
for name, group in df.groupby('date', sort=False):
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(group['values'])),
                              columns=['col']).groupby('col').size(),
                               columns=[name]).reset_index())
```

and I get the following (just showing dfs[0] and dfs[1] but I have up to dfs[8]:

```
   [   col1 col2
    0  val1 val2,
    ...
       col1 col2
    0  val1 val2]
    ...
```

And I just want to merge them all on the col1 key. In other words the following works great but how do I do it without hardcoding the individual elements in the list and loop through all of them in dfs?

```
pd.concat([dfs[0], dfs[1]], axis=1, join='outer')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='outer')
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I'm not sure why I didn't try that. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Because this had to work on a very large dataset I went with the following implementation which doesn't seem very elegant at all but performs pretty well on large datasets:

```
for name, group in df.groupby('date', sort=False):
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(group['values'])),
                              columns=['key']).groupby('key').size(),
                               columns=[name.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]).reset_index())

df2 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='outer')

df3 = pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.merge(df2.iloc[:, :2], 
        pd.DataFrame(list(set(chain.from_iterable(df['values']))), columns=['key']), how='right'),
            df2.iloc[:, 2:4], how='left'),
            df2.iloc[:, 4:6], how='left'),
            df2.iloc[:, 6:8], how='left'),
            df2.iloc[:, 8:10], how='left'),
            df2.iloc[:, 10:12], how='left'),
            df2.iloc[:, 12:14], how='left'),
            df2.iloc[:, 14:16], how='left').fillna(0).set_index('key').sort_index(axis=1)
```